# How can I trigger two events with a "double" action?

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a view `Foo`, with an input field, and a wrapper view `Bar`, with a button.

When I write something in the input and then press the button, the 'change' event on Foo's model should be triggered, and then the 'click' button on Bar's, yet only the first do happen. Is there a way to trigger both, preferably at the correct order?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by change event on Foo (a view)? Do you mean a change event on perhaps `this.model` associated with your Foo view?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate, and confirm your question/setup. Based on your question, this is the setup you have. You want to change the `Foo.model` THEN trigger the `click` event on the Bar.

```
<div id="Bar">
    <div id="Foo">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <button id="barButton">Update</button>
</div>
```

It's a little bit of an odd setup. @alexanderb illustrates it the way I also think of the whole problem but I'll explain what I'd do in your scenario assuming you know something I don't about the context of the situation! :-)

If you want the `change` to be triggered on the Foo.model followed by the click event on the Bar button, all you need to do manually trigger the button click from your Foo view. To do this, you can do it one of several ways. The first is to directly trigger the event of your parent (Bar) view.

```
// When you create your Foo subview, you pass in the parent view so you can access it
var foo = new Foo({
    'parent': this // this = the barView assuming you're creating FooView inside BarView
});

// In Foo after you set your model attribute, you access the parentView
this.options.parent.$el.find('#barButton').click();  // Manually trigger the click event

    // or

this.options.parent.onButtonClick() // Manually run the event handler bypassing the event
```

This satisfies your request to have the change event followed by the button click event in the DOM context you provided. (Not sure why in this case but I can imagine some scenarios where something similar might be desired.)

The second way of doing it is to use an event aggregator pattern which allows your views to send and receive events to one another. In this scenario, what happens is your Foo view, after updating the model triggers an event that is listened to by your parent Bar view, upon which it executes some handler.

You can read more about event aggregator pattern in Backbone here:
[Event Aggregator Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926707/display-selected-model-from-sidebar-in-information-bar/11926812#11926812)

To be honest, I really think that alexanderb's answer is the best one for this situation unless there is something more we don't know about your special setup. But, I hope you can see and compare the two and get an idea of when and why one setup might be appropriate given a particular context.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'm a little confused. If you don't use any backbone plugis, the workflow is different.

If you press something on a screen, an event occures on view, not in model. You have to listen to that event and update the model accordingly. If you set new value in model, `change` model event will occur.

Say, you have a view `Foo` it's subview `Bar` and model `Boo`. Both views are using the same model objects.

In `Bar` view,

```
events: {
   'click .button': 'onButtonClicked';
}

onButtonClicked: function () {
   var value = this.$el('.input').val();
   this.model.set({ someValue: value});
}
```

In `Foo` view, you can listen for model changes

```
initialize: function () {
  this.model.on('change:someValue', this.onSomeValueChanged);
}
```

In `this.onSomeValueChanged` you can do, what ever you like.

Comment: This answer deserves the upvote for being the most simple and effective answer. It isn't what the author specified though... which is a Bar parent view that contains a button to be clicked after updating the model. Which is a little strange since the button is what updates the model. I provided a second answer not as the correct answer, but just to illustrate what the author is asking so that people might compare the two and understand that this answer is the better one (most likely) and why. I can imagine some scenarios where something similar to my "answer" might be desired.