# Call methods of different views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js with ASP.NET MVC 4.

I want to call methods of different view from one of the view. To make this simpler to understand I have created a small example below.

Here in the MyView2 in side the OperationCompleted method I want to call the following...

- call myMethodB of MyView 2
- call myMethodA of MyView 1
- call myMethodC of AppView

How do I do this ? I have temporarily used something like creating objects of view and calling them.

Something like this `var view1 = new MyView1();` and then `view1.myMethodA();`, there has to be a better way, Please help me find it. Thanks

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
});

// View for a Main Grid
var MyView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodA: function(){
 // do something with View 1
}
...
});


// View for subgrid in Main Grid
var MyView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodB: function(){
 // do something with View 2
},
OperationCompleted: function(){
 // call myMethodB of MyView 2
 // call myMethodA of MyView 1
 // call myMethodC of AppView
}
...
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodC: function(){
 // do something with App View 
}
...
});
```

Comment: I do not see the problem.  If you have instantiated your views, they should be accessible by their instance variables.

Comment: Are you trying to find a nice way to communicate between your views? eg, something happens in one, 'I want to let related views know I've updated'? Or you really just trying to call methods off view instances?

Comment: @Layoric yes yes "something happens in one, 'I want to let related views know I've update'", this is the exact scenario –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working ! had to use the Aggregator pattern, have pasted below a sample example of how I used it...

```
Backbone.View.prototype.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.eventAggregator.bind("doSomething_event", this.doSomething);
    },
    doSomething: function(name){
        alert("Hey " + name + " !");
    }   
});

var view2 = Backbone.View.extend({    
    callToDoSomething: function(){
        self.eventAggregator.trigger("doSomething_event", "Yasser");
    }   
});
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926812/1182982

Comment: Same solution I was going to share :) I put up a repo of a basic Backbone app that has a semi clean pattern (includes extending Backbone.Events). https://github.com/Layoric/BackboneKickstart

Comment: you may want to look at Marionette for full implementation of these patterns and more.

Answer (score 1):

Another pattern here would be to call a view's function by triggering an event on the DOM element the view is attached to.

**For example:**

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: 'body',
  events: {
    'alertMe': 'alertMe'
  },
  alertMe: function(ev, arg){
    console.log(args)
    alert("You've been alerted!")
  }
});
```

Then at some point later in your code (even in another view):

```
// Shows an alert and prints object.
$('body').trigger('alertMe', { foo: 'bar' });
```