# Call different functions of different views of backbone.js from a global function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call methods of different views in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720561/call-methods-of-different-views-in-backbone-js)

I am new to backbone.js and I am using backbone.js with ASP.NET MVC 4.

I have a global class called SomeObject in which I have a deleteUser function. This function is binded with one of the click event of a button present in MyView2.

How do I call the following backbone.js different functions present in different views, from this global function/class.

- call myMethodB of MyView 2
- call myMethodA of MyView 1
- call myMethodC of AppView

Please guide me on this. I am still learning backbone.js and might be doing something wrong. Thanks

```
var SomeObject = function (Id, Name) {
    var self = this;
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.deleteUser = function () {
        console.log(self.Id, self.Name);

        // call myMethodB of MyView 2
        // call myMethodA of MyView 1
        // call myMethodC of AppView
    };
};

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
});

// View for a Main Grid
var MyView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodA: function(){
 // do something with View 1
}
...
});


// View for subgrid in Main Grid
var MyView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodB: function(){
 // do something with View 2
}   
...
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
myMethodC: function(){
 // do something with App View 
}
...
});
```

Comment: @muistooshort pls read the **full question** again, its different from the prev question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Backbone events - http://backbonejs.org/#Events

```
var SomeObject = function (Id, Name) {
    var self = this;
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.deleteUser = function () {
        console.log(self.Id, self.Name);

        viewInstances.MyView2.trigger('eventFormyMethodB')
        viewInstances.MyView1.trigger('eventFormyMethodA')
        viewInstances.AppView.trigger('eventFormyMethodC')
    };
};

var viewInstances = {
    MyView2: new MyView2({...}),
    MyView1: new MyView1({...}),
    AppView: new AppView({...})
}
```

For example

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
    events: {
        'eventFormyMethodC': 'myMethodC'
    },
    myMethodC: function(){
    // do something with App View 
    }
...
});
```